# follow url before hiding anchor-tag

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, anchor, onblur

I have an autocomplete search form, more or less like the one used on facebook, where I start typing and a list of names shows up.
I made links of each of these names so you can open their profile page.
I also have a function on the search form's input field 'onblur', where I hide the autocomplete div with all the names. So that when I click outside it, it doesn't stay visible. The only problem now is that when I click one of the names, the pages doesn't redirect to the profile page of the anchor tag, even though the cursor does change on hover.

Anybody any idea?

Comment: What is the code u have so far?

Comment: Show some code, use jsfiddle.net. Use prepared data to load few profiles instead using faceboook api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your hide event removes the list before the element can actually be clicked. There are couple of solutions.

First you could use a setTimeout to hide

```
setTimeout( function() { /* hide list */ }, 500);
```

In answer to your comment, no, you can't reorder events. So you will have to find a work around. There are a number of methods, but since you are using jQuery I would do it this way.

```
//you probably have something like this currently
$('element').blur( function() { $('results').hide(); });    

//change it to something like this
$('element').blur( function() { $('results').fadeOut(300); });
```

Comment: ok, I could indeed timout the hide event. Hadn't thought of it that way. Is there another way of prioritizing the click event before the hide event? And yes, I'm using jquery.

Comment: @dreagan  - No, you can't reorder events. I'll update my answer with a couple solutions.